# Aggregation in elastic search by field value data

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have below set of data and I want aggregation as per the status. Not sure how to compare the value of status with rejected or success and get the count of result.

```
{
    "took": 4,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 3,
        "successful": 3,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2874,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "testfiles",
                "_type": "testfiles",
                "_id": "testfile.one",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "businessDate": 20171013,
                    "status": "Success"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "testfiles",
                "_type": "testfiles",
                "_id": "testfile.two",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "businessDate": 20171013,
                    "status": "Success"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "testfiles",
                "_type": "testfiles",
                "_id": "testfile.three",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "businessDate": 20171013,
                    "status": "Rejected"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "testfiles",
                "_type": "testfiles",
                "_id": "testfile.four",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "businessDate": 20171013,
                    "status": "Rejected"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Can someone help to how to achieve this in elastic search aggregation.

Expected response something like below

```
"aggregations": {
        "success_records": 2,
        "rejected_records": 2
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `status` field is of type `text`, you'll need to update it to [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/multi-fields.html#multi-fields) having a `keyword` type needed for aggregation. Then query using:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "statuses": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "status.raw"
      }
  }
}
```

If you already have `status` as `keyword` field, then change `status.raw` to `status` in the above query.

Comment: That's right, in the new versions the type string was split in two text and keyword. As @Chandra  said you have to use keyword type.

Comment: Chandra Praneeth Could I ask you a question about elasticsearch?

Comment: @RodriKing, tell me about it

Comment: I want to make a wildcard query, but wildcard queries do not apply to analized/filters (match query does). I want to apply the analysis of ignoring the accents of the words. As with wildcard queries I can't, I'm using query string queries. Would that be correct?

Comment: @RodriKing, sorry for delayed response, can you create a new question with more details